# Extract sub-string from the column value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I came from Tableau background , So kindly please help me I am in my beginning stage.

I am holding a column where it's value is like

```
Q3 2018 
Q4 2018 
Q3 2019
Q4 2019
Q1 2019 
Q2 2019
```

And I need to split this value into two new columns one in the quarter and other is Year.

Can anyone please help me how can I make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Open query editor

[image]

2) Make the column you want to split active by clicking on it, then on the "Transform" tab choose "Split Columns \ By delimiter "

[image]
[image]

The result:

[image]

After, rename the columns